# Batch Files: Processing files in alphbetical (Numerical maybe>) Order

Tags: windows, image, batch-file, alphabetical

I am currently trying to process a bunch of files with imagemagick
using a batch file in windows, they are all numbered numerically as
follows:
image00
image01,
image02,
...,
image010,
image011,
...,
image0100,
image0101

and so on, but when i try to process the file it wants to run though
image00, image01, image010, image0100, image0101, image0102 and so on.

my code is as follows

`SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

SET COUNT=0

FOR %%a in (*.bmp) DO

(

IF !ERRORLEVEL!==0

(

SET TFILE=0!COUNT!

SET TFILE=Terrain!TFILE:~-4!.jpg

SET /A COUNT+=1

ECHO %%a >output.txt

convert %%a -compress LOSSLESS !TFILE!

)

)`

is there any way i can make it so that it will process these files in order, for the time being i have a work-around but it means that i continually have to change some script files when the images are used later on. I would much rather have all of the files be the same 'Terrain' name with incrementing number following.

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Why does it matter which order the files are processed in?

Comment: Well my code takes larger images and gets a sub image decided on longitude and latiude and pixels per minute, then divides them up into smaller images and numbers them, i want to take those images, rename them and keep them in the same numerical order, i WAS using a counter but have slightly changed how i did it and am now using sub strings, so it doesn't matter which order they process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can probably create some more batch code to "sort" the numbers by order, however, since you can use imagemagick, i suppose you can also download other stuff. my suggestion is you can try and use GNU sort (in [coreutils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) ). Then in your batch , do some thing like this

pseudocode :

```
for ... ( dir /b *bmp | gnu_sort -n ) do (
  echo "do your stuff"
)
```

you could probably check whether the sort that comes with Windows has a numerical sorting option. (the last time i check it doesn't have this option).

Answer (score 1):

You could rename the files to be image000 image001, image002, ..., image010,

You could split up the file name something like this:

```
@echo off 

    setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 

    if not defined TRACE (
        set TRACE=REM
    )

    %TRACE% On 

    for %%a In (data\*.*)  do call :EachFile %%a 


    endlocal

goto :eof 


:EachFile %%a 
    set Name=%~n1
    @Echo %Name%

    set NUm=%Name:~6,9%
    set /a Num=Num+100000
    @echo %Num%

    echo ren %1  %~dp1Image%Num%%~x1
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to find, because it's not really obvious from the documentation. The solution is to use the FOR command in combination with the dir command. I would do something like this:

```
@echo off
ECHO Listed in name order: %1 
ECHO ------------------------------------------------------
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b /o:n %1') DO echo %%G
```